# MongoDB Mergelist error in Debian 6.0.9

Tags: debian-squeeze, mongodb

We installed Ubiquiti UniFi 2.4.6 which installs Mongodb 10gen on Debian Squeeze 6.0.9.  This was a clean install, with no other packages installed from the base install (other than SSH).  I was able to successfully install both UniFi and Mongodb, but received the following when running an apt-get update:

Pertinent error:

****Reading package lists... Error!**

****E: Encountered a section with no Package: header**

**E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/downloads-distro.mongdb.org_repo_ubuntu-upstart_dists_dist_10gen_binary-i386_Packages**

**E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.******

I've ran a sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf followed by an apt-get clean && apt-get update with the same error appearing. (I did back up the lists directory.  Any ideas?)

As an aside, I should mention, that I tried to remove unifi and it probably goes without saying it won't uninstall.

Here's a head of downloads-distro.mongdb.org_repo_ubuntu-upstart_dists_dist_10gen_binary-i386_Packages  **(removed the *links*)**

mongdb.org
script src="*://www.google.(com)/adsense/domains/caf.js" type="text/javascript" >
="*://d1vbm0eveofcle.cloudfront.(net)/themes/assets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

="*://d1vbm0eveofcle.cloudfront.(net)/themes/cleanPeppermintBlack/style5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

link='*://fonts.googleapis.(com)/css?family=Libre+Baskerville:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

root@:/var/l

Full apt-get update:

Get:1 *://security.debian.(org)squeeze/updates Release.gpg [836 B]

Ign *://security.debian.(org)/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en

Ign *://security.debian.(org)/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en_US

Hit *://ftp.us.debian.(org)squeeze Release.gpg

Ign *://ftp.us.debian.(org)/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-en

Ign *://ftp.us.debian.(org)/debian/ squeeze/main Translation-en_US

Get:2 *://ftp.us.debian.(org)squeeze-updates Release.gpg [836 B]

Get:3 *://security.debian.(org)squeeze/updates Release [86.9 kB]

Ign *://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates/main Translation-en

Ign *://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates/main Translation-en_US

Hit *://ftp.us.debian.(org)squeeze Release

Get:4 *://ftp.us.debian.(org)squeeze-updates Release [113 kB]

Hit *://www.ubnt.(com)squeeze Release.gpg

Ign *://www.ubnt.(com)/downloads/unifi/distros/deb/squeeze/ squeeze/ubiquiti Translation-en

Get:5 *://security.debian.(org)squeeze/updates/main Sources [172 kB]

Get:6 *://downloads-distro.mongdb.(org)dist Release.gpg

Ign *://www.ubnt.(com)/downloads/unifi/distros/deb/squeeze/ squeeze/ubiquiti Translation-en_US

Get:7 *://downloads-distro.mongdb.(org)/repo/ubuntu-upstart/ dist/10gen Translation-en

Get:8 *://downloads-distro.mongdb.(org)/repo/ubuntu-upstart/ dist/10gen Translation-en_US

Hit *://ftp.us.debian.(org)squeeze/main Sources

Hit *://ftp.us.debian.(org)squeeze/main i386 Packages

Get:9 *://security.debian.(org)squeeze/updates/main i386 Packages [457 kB]

Get:10 *://ftp.us.debian.(org)squeeze-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex [3,955 B]

Get:11 *://ftp.us.debian.(org)squeeze-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex [3,955 B]

Get:12 *://ftp.us.debian.(org)squeeze-updates/main i386 Packages [5,228 B]

Get:13 *://downloads-distro.mongdb.(org)dist Release

Ign *://downloads-distro.mongdb.org dist Release

Hit *://www.ubnt.(com)squeeze Release

Get:14 *://downloads-distro.mongdb.(org)dist/10gen i386 Packages/DiffIndex

Get:15 *://downloads-distro.mongdb.(org)dist/10gen i386 Packages

Hit *://www.ubnt.(com)squeeze/ubiquiti i386 Packages

Fetched 882 kB in 1s (596 kB/s)

Reading package lists... Error!

E: Encountered a section with no Package: header

E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/downloads-distro.mongdb.org_repo_ubuntu-upstart_dists_dist_10gen_binary-i386_Packages

E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to install MongoDB with the Ubuntu installation method, rather than [the Debian installation method](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/). Try again and this time use the correct installation method.

Comment: Got it, but I can't even remove the MongoDB gen10 to begin with.  Ideas on how to do that?